# Variable out of scope but in scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I have a jquery function that adds an event listener to various elements to execute on click. For some reason, when I try to reference a global variable *(daySelected)* inside the function, it says it is undefined. Am I missing something?

```js
var daySelected = false;

$('.deal-day').bind('click', function(e) {
  console.log("Day Selected: " + daySelected);
  if (!daySelected) {
    if($(this).hasClass('selected-filter')) {
      $(this).removeClass('selected-filter');
      var daySelected = false;
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('selected-filter');
      var daySelected = true;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: remove the `var` from where you have `daySelected = true` and `daySelected = false` inside the event listener. These are currently their own local variables which shadow the global - so the global remains false.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thank you so much! I did not know that would override the global, regardless it was still an error anyways. Thanks!!

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple `var daySelected`.
`var` should be defined only once. Otherwise you're creating new scopes.

As a general fix you could improve the code like:

```js
let daySelected = false;         // Feel free to change this boolean
const $dealDay = $(".deal-day"); // Get all buttons with that class
const toggleDaySelectedButtons = () => $dealDay.toggleClass("selected-filter", daySelected); 

$dealDay.on("click", function(e) {
  daySelected = !daySelected; // Toggle boolean
  toggleDaySelectedButtons(); // Handle buttons
});

toggleDaySelectedButtons(); // Do on DOM ready
```

```css
.selected-filter {background: gold;}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="deal-day">Filter deal day</button>
<hr>
<button type="button" class="deal-day">Filter deal day</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I really hope you have only one `.deal-day` button - otherwise the above will not be ideal

Comment: If you're improving code, the global variable is unnecessary.  The constant selector may also be unwarranted.